# "UNION-ALL" Causing Answer Submission to Fail

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, answers

I was attempting to answer a question on StackOverflow, but repeatedly ran into an error while submitting my answer.  When I clicked "Post Your Answer", it would hang for a while and then fail; giving me the error message "An error occurred submitting the answer".

At first I thought it was a momentary glitch, so I copy/pasted my answer to a file to retry later.  After repeatedly getting this error from many attempts over the course of a few hours, I tried submitting the answer piecemeal to see if StackOverflow would accept part of the answer.  In the end, I found it to be due to the use of "UNION-ALL" (without the dash).  If I put a dash between "UNION" and "ALL", my answer would save fine.  If I removed it, I would encounter the error again.  In addition, I encountered the same problem when simply trying to type "UNION-ALL" in the comments on the question and I'm encountering it here.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Is this a bug in StackOverflow?

Here is a link to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714209/1438242) I posted.

Comment: @michaelb958 You got it before I did.. :(

Comment: @hichris123 **First!** `XD`

Comment: This is a duplicate.  Thanks @michaelb958.  I'd close the question if I had enough reputation to do so here.

Comment: @michaelb958 one minute and forty seven seconds... you call that fast? Oded do it in less than ten seconds! ;)